# Setting Firefox Zoom Level using user.js file

Tags: javascript, firefox, config, settings, zooming

I want to adapt the standard zoom level in firefox to be 110% using the user.js file. (Or any other file that will work :) )
My problem is that I can't find which option I have to change to adapt the zoom.

A info link so that you can actually figure out what I am talking about:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Preferences/A_brief_guide_to_Mozilla_preferences

greetings